# Update post / page using API + python

Tags: rest-api, api, wp-update-post, python

I'm trying to update posts using python and API, the issue that I keep getting code 200 but the post doesn't actually get updated!

here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

url ='http://www.***.com/wp-json/wp/v2'

username="------"
password="------"

creds = username + ':' + password
cred_token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())

header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + cred_token.decode('utf-8')}


postID = "36559"
post = {
 'content' : "Hello, this content updated."
}

blog = requests.post(url + "/posts/" + postID , headers=header, json=post)
print(blog)
```

I also tried, but kept getting response 404:

```
blog = requests.post(url + "/" + postID , headers=header, json=post)
```

**Edit - Solution:**
the issue was that the url had http and not https, it seems i have to use the https version, although its weird I kept getting 200 response.
Now it works

Comment: I don’t know Python, but it looks like you’re using the POST method. To update posts you need to send a PUT request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie same issue, I get response 200, but the post doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - Solution:**
the issue was that the url had http and not https, it seems i have to use the https version, although its weird I kept getting 200 response before.